# How to change all words in Replace function

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I would like to explain my problem of the day.

today i think my problem is not too complicated finally i hope

in the following code, 
I am looking to use the function "replace"

and my problem is as follows, 
I replace "Microsoft" by "W3Schools", 
it works correctly except that I have to double click on "try it" 
to change the Word twice "Microsoft" .

and so I would rather change all the words "Microsoft" ,
with just one click

Do you have an idea of how to fix this? Neff

```
<p id="demo">Visit Microsoft! Visit Microsoft!</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use a regular expression with global (`g`) flag - `str.replace(/Microsoft/g, 'W3Schools');`

Comment: You will need to use the regex variant with the global flag.. -> `'Visit Microsoft! Visit Microsoft!'.replace(/Microsoft/g,'W3Schools')`

Comment: you can use regEx ```str.replace(/Microsoft/g,'W3school')```

Comment: @fubar /Keith /Mohit Karkar 
that works thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
str.replace("/Microsoft/g", "W3Schools");
```

/Microsoft/g - where g - means global replacement of wherever it finds Microsoft in the string it replaces with W3Schools

For case insensitivity, you should use gi instead of g

```
str.replace("/Microsoft/gi", "W3Schools");
```

Answer (score 1):

try using regex

```
var res = str.replace(/Microsoft/g, "W3Schools");
```

instead of

```
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
```